# How to find the best fit margins distribution to my data

Tags: r, distributions, goodness-of-fit

I have data as follow:

```
 x <- c(3,  12 ,   2 ,   4 , 19 ,  19 ,  21 ,  49 ,  36 ,  34 ,  18,   69 ,  83 ,  34 ,  46 ,  41 ,  27  , 22  , 33   , 7  ,  7  , 13 ,  80 ,  36,
65  , 97 ,  83,   69 ,  76,  198,  118,  114,   56,   84 ,  24,  225 ,  85 , 200,  148 , 164 , 157 , 131,  170,  267 , 178,  171 , 203 , 440, 282,  161,  109, 131,  230 , 149 , 194 , 142,  316 , 363,  520,  443,  673,  478,  419,  839,  488,  642,  730,  815,  714,  856,  794,  742,
765,  789,  739,  611,  483,  679,  504,  668,  556,  683,  675,  719,  900,  717,  746, 1099, 1317, 1431, 1584, 1089, 1735, 1658, 1629)
```

and

```
    y <– c(23.2, 24.7, 22.3, 21.9, 23.4, 26.4, 22.9, 22.9, 24.8, 21.3, 18.0, 19.8, 23.4, 26.4 ,27.4 ,29.3 ,25.1, 22.7, 23.0, 26.3, 28.8, 27.8, 25.0 ,27.3,
 29.0 ,30.3, 31.5, 33.3, 33.5, 29.0, 25.0, 22.4, 22.4, 22.9, 23.8, 26.1, 25.5, 26.0, 25.0, 21.7 ,25.5,29.3, 30.8, 32.9 ,31.8, 27.3, 28.5, 31.7,
  31.6 ,29.8, 31.5 ,29.8, 30.3, 33.3, 32.2, 29.1 ,28.7, 33.0, 32.8, 30.5, 30.6, 30.4, 30.4, 30.8 ,32.1, 32.9, 33.4, 33.6, 34.1, 34.0 ,32.6 ,32.9,
   34.0, 34.9, 32.0, 32.8 ,34.6 ,35.3 ,35.7 ,35.4, 35.1, 36.2 ,37.3, 36.6, 36.8, 36.6,35.6, 36.3, 37.4, 37.0, 37.2 ,37.0, 35.8, 34.7, 35.9)
```

I tried to identify the best fit distribution of each variable, x, and y. I searched for the
this point and I found that I can do it using `fitdistrplus` function in R.

I tried to apply what I learned to my data, but I fail to understand the result.

```
 library(fitdistrplus)
library(logspline)
descdist(x, discrete = FALSE)
fw <- fitdist(x, "weibull")
fg <- fitdist(x, "gamma") ## this line returns me an error so I did not run the following line for it. 
fe <- fitdist(x, "exp")
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot.legend <- c("Weibull","expo")
denscomp(list(fw, fe), legendtext = plot.legend)
qqcomp(list(fw,fe), legendtext = plot.legend)
cdfcomp(list(fw, fe), legendtext = plot.legend)
ppcomp(list(fw, fe), legendtext = plot.legend)
```

I found from the plot that "Weibull" and "expo" may better fit to variable `X`, however, Q-Qplot shows that both of them are not good estimation to `X`.

My problem:

I do not understand how to read the result of the `descdist` function. How can I understand the plot? In other words, how can I identify the best fit distribution from the plot of `descdist`?

Any help or idea, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the description of the function `descdist`:

> Minimum, maximum, median, mean, sample sd, and sample (if
> method=="sample") or by default unbiased estimations of skewness and
> Pearsons's kurtosis values are printed (Sokal and Rohlf, 1995). A
> skewness-kurtosis plot such as the one proposed by Cullen and Frey
> (1999) is given for the empirical distribution. On this plot, values
> for common distributions are also displayed as a tools to help the
> choice of distributions to fit to data. For some distributions
> (normal, uniform, logistic, exponential for example), there is only
> one possible value for the skewness and the kurtosis (for a normal
> distribution for example, skewness = 0 and kurtosis = 3), and the
> distribution is thus represented by a point on the plot. For other
> distributions, areas of possible values are represented, consisting in
> lines (gamma and lognormal distributions for example), or larger areas
> (beta distribution for example). The Weibull distribution is not
> represented on the graph but it is indicated on the legend that shapes
> close to lognormal and gamma distributions may be obtained with this
> distribution.

So that's exactly what it does. It seems like it gives the 'best' parameters for your distribution **conditional** on it actually following one of those popular distributions. So if your data was indeed normally distributed, what is the 'best' mean and variance that defines it? And so on.

As for "I tried to identify the best fit distribution of each variable", the best fit distribution given sample data $x$ is literally the empirical CDF (ECDF) given this data.  In general, the class of possible distributions is too large to test for 'the best distribution' given any amount of data (distributions for continuous variables are strictly increasing continuous functions that tend to $1$ at positive limit and $0$ at negative limit, and this class of functions is enormous). Furthermore, an arbitrary distribution is extremely unlikely to truly corresponds to one of the standard distributions we often consider. In some sense, this is why we work with parameters such as the mean, median, quantile, variance, etc of a random variable: they are features of the distribution that tell us interesting things without having to search over this entire function space.

Given this issue, a common approach is to instead either 1. compare the distribution to a fixed distribution, or a fixed subset of distributions. For example, we could compare it to the class of all normal distributions.

Comment: I think you mixed up densities (integrate to 1) with cumulative probabilities (increasing).

Comment: @AlexR whelp! You're right, edited!